# Delete Image from UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController set up so that I can add photos from camera or library and the pageviewcontroller resets itself every time the imagepickercontroller is called so the pageviewcontrol updates and shows.  It works perfectly (i think).  What i know want to do is have the option to delete one of the photos then call the same reset.

The problem is, i can not get an accurate index value of the current image being displayed in the pageviewcontroller.  I try to grab the index from the viewControllerBeforeViewController or AfterViewController or the pagecontrolleratindex... but the index does not follow correctly the way the pagecontrol is designed.  I read about willtransitiontoviewcontrollers and didfinsihanimating, but those are not being called, i am thinking because i am getting the images from an array and not new view controllers.

My method to delete works, but the index is not accurate so even though the second image is shown the first image could be the one deleted.

Is there a good way to get the current displayed array index so i can delete the image from array?  //this array holds images from imagepicker, i call the restartviewcontrollers evertime there is an imagepicked to update the number of pages and this works.

UPDATE

```
var pageViewController:UIPageViewController!
var pageImages: [UIImage]? = [] //this array holds images from imagepicker, i call the restartviewcontrollers evertime there is an imagepicked to update the number of pages and this works.
var deletePageIndex: Int = 0


func pageViewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> PhotoContentPageViewController {

    if (self.pageImages!.count == 0 || index >= self.pageImages!.count) {
        return PhotoContentPageViewController()
    }

    var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotoPageContentStoryBoard") as! PhotoContentPageViewController

    vc.imageFileName = pageImages![index] as! UIImage
    vc.pageIndex = index

    return vc
}

func restartViewController() {
    var startVc = self.pageViewControllerAtIndex(0) as PhotoContentPageViewController
    var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVc)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func startViewControllers() {
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotoPageViewControllerStoryBoard") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    pageViewController.delegate = self

    var startVc = self.pageViewControllerAtIndex(0) as PhotoContentPageViewController
    var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVc)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -10, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-30)
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}



func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var vc = viewController as! PhotoContentPageViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }

    index--

    return self.pageViewControllerAtIndex(index)
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var vc = viewController as! PhotoContentPageViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }

    index++

    if (index == self.pageImages!.count) {
        return nil
    }

    return self.pageViewControllerAtIndex(index)
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {


}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (!completed) {
        return
    }

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you actually are using a UIPageViewControllerDelegate, you can use **willtransitiontoviewcontrollers** but that method only works if you set the **delegate** property of the page view controller to your view controller. That way, you can simply get the index of the current view controller in page view controller and use it for deletion.

```
myPageViewController.delegate = self
```

And make sure your view controller implements UIPageViewControllerDelegate

**UPDATE**
Assuming that you have an array of you view controllers, you could implement your data source like this:

```
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController)?.advancedBy(1) where index < pages.count {
        return pages[index]
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let index = pages.indexOf(viewController)?.advancedBy(-1) where index > -1 {
        return pages[index]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, i implemented the delegate and also did you suggestion, the willtransitiontoviewcontroller and didfinishanimated are both being called now... however, still having an issue finding the exact code in those functions to get the index.. i saw in other posts to implement `code pendingIndex = pageViewController.viewControllers!.first!.view.tag` but that doesn't seem to get any index.. any final help would be appreciated.

Comment: thank for all the help, but got frustrated so decided just to post code.. let me know what you think to get current index if you can.. just not working.  think i need to get current image array index maybe?